# How to remove Expires header with Spring cache control

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, spring-security

Spring Security adds the following cache headers by default:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

That's a good setting for our HTML pages. For static resources (images, CSS etc.) we would like to have them cached. According to the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-cache-control), it can be configured like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
            .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
}
```

That results in the following HTTP headers:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Pragma: 
Expires: 0
```

That's good except for the `Expires` header, which still indicates that document should not be cached. (The standard says that `max-age` takes precedence over `Expires`. But our intermediate cache still treats it as non cacheable.)

How can we remove the `Expires` header (or set it to blank) for cacheable documents? Why doesn't Spring remove it if we configure a cache period?

Comment: What version of spring-web are you using? If you are using spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar it is possible you are running into https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14005 Can you see if the same problem occurs with spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar

Comment: We're still at 4.2.4. So it's not related to SPR-14005. However in one of the bug's comments, there is a sample of how to exclude certain resources from Spring Security. That's a working solution for us. Do you want to add is as an answer? Thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response and feedback. Please do not use the workarounds on that JIRA. See my answer below for details

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be related to [spring-security#3759](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/3759). You can work around this by ignoring specific URLs as listed on (somewhat unrelated) [SPR-14005](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14005). However, this is not advised (even if the URLs point to static resources) since it means all security is disabled for the URLs.

Instead, users should consider using this workaround:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        RequestMatcher notResourcesMatcher = new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/resources/**"));
        HeaderWriter notResourcesHeaderWriter = new DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter(notResourcesMatcher , new CacheControlHeadersWriter());
        http
            .headers()
                .cacheControl().disable()
                .addHeaderWriter(notResourcesHeaderWriter);
    }
}
```

When Spring Security 4.1 is released [spring-security#3759](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/3759) will be fixed and this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ResourceHttpRequestHandler.useExpriresHeader` to `false`.

Unfortunaly there is no such flag in the configuration object `ResourceHandlerRegistry`. So you need to do it on your own:

The following is just an idea, **I have not checked** that this method does not configure any other `HandlerMapping` than the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`

```
@Override
@Bean
public HandlerMapping resourceHandlerMapping() {
    ResourceHandlerRegistry registry = new ResourceHandlerRegistry(this.applicationContext, this.servletContext);
    addResourceHandlers(registry);

    AbstractHandlerMapping handlerMapping = registry.getHandlerMapping();
    if (handlerMapping != null) {
        handlerMapping.setPathMatcher(mvcPathMatcher());
        handlerMapping.setUrlPathHelper(mvcUrlPathHelper());
        handlerMapping.setInterceptors(new HandlerInterceptor[] {
                new ResourceUrlProviderExposingInterceptor(mvcResourceUrlProvider())});

        //this line!!!:
        ((ResourceHttpRequestHandler)handlerMapping).setUseExpiresHeader(false);
    }
    else {
        handlerMapping = new EmptyHandlerMapping();
    }
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it is *false* by default. Furthermore, `useExpiresHeader` is deprecated. So this code won't change anything. My debugging has additionally shown that Spring Security inserts the *Expires* header early in the request processing. So `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` would need to actively unset it. Setting it to *true* might even make more sense...